# Google action. UI is not updated when report state change

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am trying to build a custom google action.

When my device is changing state (for example the user is turning the light on).I am updating the graph database to let the device know that a change happened.

The ReportState call works correctly (I get an HTTP `200` code). When I ask the google assistant for the device state, it gives me the correct information.

But the UI in Google home is not changing.

I read somewhere that is the way it works. Just like to have a confirmation on that, as it will confuse a lot of users...

Comment: You will need to refresh the UI. I think pull to refresh works.

Answer (score 0):

This is the current behavior in the user interface. If you're receiving a `200` status code, you're doing it correctly.